# How to display multidimensional array data in a table

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(6) "Blobby"
    ["avatar"]=>
    string(116) "url"
    ["balance"]=>
    string(7) "8289061"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(6) "Snipey"
    ["avatar"]=>
    string(116) "url"
    ["balance"]=>
    string(6) "208841"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(4) "Xg45"
    ["avatar"]=>
    string(116) "url"
    ["balance"]=>
    string(5) "20509"
  }
}
```

I am passing this data from a mysql query to a variable and i was wondering how would i display the data in a table.

```
    foreach ($leader as $key => $val) {
        if ($key != 'submit') {
            echo "<tr>" . $key['avatar'] . "</tr>";
            echo "<tr>" . $key['name'] . "</tr>";
            echo "<tr>" . $key['balance'] . "</tr>";
        }
    }
```

This is what I was trying to use but it was only displaying the first letter in each key.

Comment: Why the top level for loop ?

Comment: I have no idea it was me trying to experiment.

Comment: @Snipey please also give my answer a try, it hasn't been tested though :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<tr>` does not display anything but a table row `<tr>` with a table data `<td>` in will

Also the data is in the `$val` variable and not the `$key` variable

```
foreach ($leader as $key => $val) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $val['avatar'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $val['name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $val['balance'] . "</td>";
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Also the `if ($key != 'submit') {` line is redundant as you have a numerically indexed array so `$key` could never be `== 'submit'`

Answer (score 1):

1) The `<tr>` tag defines a row in an **HTML** table. And, The `<td>` (also known as **Standard cells**) tag defines a standard cell in an HTML table which - contains data. Use `<td>` to display data instead `<tr>`. For more info, click [table tr](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_tr.asp) and [table td](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_td.asp)

2) And, as `$key => $val`. So, data is in `$val` not in `$key`.

```
<?php
foreach ($leader as $key => $val) {
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $val['avatar'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $val['name'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $val['balance'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

?>
```

Comment: Nana; you were doing so well with giving an explanation :-) you can do this :-)

Comment: Yes. @Fred-ii- `:D` As soon I answered, I saw 4-5 answers were already there. So, I thought to leave. But, My friend As you suggested. I will do it for now.

Comment: *Done* @Fred-ii-. Thanks For Reminding Me. *Cheers Buddy*

Comment: Ahhh nice! *Cheers Nana!*

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach ($leader as $val) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $val['avatar'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $val['name'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $val['balance'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like:

```
$leader = array(
    array("name" =>"Blobby" ,"avatar"=>"url", "balance"=> "8289061"),
    array("name" =>"Snipey" ,"avatar"=>"url", "balance"=> "208841"),
    array("name" =>"Xg45" ,"avatar"=>"url", "balance"=> "Xg45")
  );

foreach($leader as $arr) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo "<td>" .$arr['name']. "</td>";
    echo "<td>" .$arr['avatar']."</td>";
    echo "<td>" .$arr['balance']."</td>";
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: Why should the OP "do like" this? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 0):

well, forget about column names and regardless of number of columns, here's the solution:

```
for ($i = 0; $ii = sizeof($leader); $i < $ii; $i++) {
    if($i == 0){
        echo "<table>";
        echo "<thead><tr>";
        foreach ($leader[$i] as $key => $val) {
            echo "<th>" . $key . "</th>";
        }       
        echo "</tr></thead>";
        echo "<tbody><tr>";
        foreach ($leader[$i] as $key => $val) {
            echo "<td>" . $val . "</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    else {
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach ($leader[$i] as $key => $val) {
            echo "<td>" . $val . "</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    if($i == $ii - 1){
        echo "</tbody>";
        echo "</table>";
    }               
}
```

It won't show anything if $leader is empty

Answer (score -1):

Try following:

```
        foreach($leader as $arrLeader)
        {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $arrLeader['avatar'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $arrLeader['name'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $arrLeader['balance'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use from this code:

```
<table>
     <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>
                   avatar
              </th>
              <th>
                   name
              </th>
              <th>
                   balance
              </th>
         </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
          <?php foreach($leader as $key => $value): ?>
          <tr>
              <td>
                   <?php echo $value['avatar'] ?>
              </td>
              <td>
                   <?php echo $value['name'] ?>
              </td>
              <td>
                   <?php echo $value['balance'] ?>
              </td>
          </tr>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
      </tbody>
</table>
```